# How can I make a loop so that the point gets added up to "user" or "comp" at every turn?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a stone paper scissor game by python. In it, the user, as well as the computer, will get 3 chances. Whoever wins a round will get `1` point. Every round a point gets added to the one who wins.

Here is the code:

```
from random import choice
def stone_paper_scissor(): #g = guess
  print("Choose either of the following:")
  print("     stone, paper, scissor")
  for i in range(3):
    guess = ("stone", "paper", "scissor")# guess
    user_g = input('ENTER YOUR GUESS:')
    user_g.lower()
    comp_g = choice(guess) #computer"s guess
    comp = 0 # computer's score
    user = 0 # user's score
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # when both parties guess are the same
    if comp_g == user_g:
        print( "--------------------------------------" )
        print( "IT'S A DRAW!" )
        print( "--------------------------------------" )
        break
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # when computer chooses stone(guess[0])
    if comp_g == guess[0]:
         if user_g == guess[1]:
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print( "YOU WIN!" )
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print("COMPUTER"+ comp_g)
               print("USER"+ user_g)
               user += 1
               print("USER: %d" %(user))
               print("COMPUTER: %d" %(comp))
         elif user_g == guess[2]:
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print( "YOU LOSE!" )
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print("COMPUTER"+ comp_g)
               print("USER"+ user_g)
               comp += 1
               print("USER: %d" %(user))
               print("COMPUTER: %d" %(comp))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # when computer chooses paper(guess[1])
    if comp_g == guess[1]:
         if user_g == guess[0]:
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print( "YOU LOSE!" )
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print("COMPUTER"+ comp_g)
               print("USER"+ user_g)
               comp += 1
               print("USER: %d" %(user))
               print("COMPUTER: %d" %(comp))
         elif user_g == guess[2]:
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print( "YOU WIN!" )
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print("COMPUTER" + comp_g)
               print("USER" + user_g)
               user += 1
               print("USER:  %d" %(user))
               print("COMPUTER: %d" %(comp))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # when computer chooses scissor (guess[2])
    if comp_g == guess[2]:
         if user_g ==  guess[0]:
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print( "YOU WIN!" )
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print("COMPUTER"+ comp_g)
               print("USER"+ user_g)
               user += 1
               print("USER:  %d" %(user))
               print("COMPUTER:  %d" %(comp))
         elif user_g == guess[1]:
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print( "YOU LOSE!" )
               print( "----------------------------------" )
               print("COMPUTER"+ comp_g)
               print("USER"+ user_g)
               comp += 1
               print("USER: %d" %(user))
               print("COMPUTER: %d" %(comp))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



print(stone_paper_scissor())
```

Here is the output which I expect:

```
Choose either of the following:
     stone, paper, scissor
ENTER YOUR GUESS:paper
----------------------------------
YOU WIN!
----------------------------------
COMPUTER:stone
USER:paper
USER: 1
COMPUTER: 0
ENTER YOUR GUESS:scissor
----------------------------------
YOU WIN!
----------------------------------
COMPUTER:paper
USER:scissor
USER:  2
COMPUTER: 0
ENTER YOUR GUESS:paper
----------------------------------
YOU LOSE!
----------------------------------
COMPUTER:scissor
USER:paper
USER: 2
COMPUTER: 1
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the output which I am obtaining is not expected:

```
Choose either of the following:
     stone, paper, scissor
ENTER YOUR GUESS:paper
----------------------------------
YOU WIN!
----------------------------------
COMPUTER:stone
USER:paper
USER: 1
COMPUTER: 0
ENTER YOUR GUESS:scissor
----------------------------------
YOU WIN!
----------------------------------
COMPUTER:paper
USER:scissor
USER:  1
COMPUTER: 0
ENTER YOUR GUESS:paper
----------------------------------
YOU LOSE!
----------------------------------
COMPUTER:scissor
USER:paper
USER: 0
COMPUTER: 1
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I know the reason behind the error(I am making the entire program under the `def()` a loop. As a result, I am getting an unexpected result). I actually want to get a solution from the community to resolve my issue.Every suggestion will be appreciated.

**THANK YOU**

*(IDE used: Pycharm)*

Comment: Just move `comp = 0` and `user = 0` _above_ the `for` loop so they are not reset to `0` in each iteration.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest defining a helper method for printing the current score so you don't have to repeat that part 6 times. Also, you should check that the user's input is valid.

Comment: Just by the way here, but rock-paper-scissors against a randomly-playing computer boils down to a simple choice between a loss, a win, and a tie. You don't need to make the computer play a hand and then compare it to the user's hand. The user knows what hand they played, and they can deduce what hand the computer played by looking at whether it was a win, loss, or tie. If you really want to display that information, calculate the computer's hand after the result has been randomly chosen.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I somewhat disagree. Yes, in the current implementation the result would be the same, but anyway you either have to determine the hand from the result or the result from the hand, and the way it is now is both more intuitive, and it could be extended to different computer strategies (e.g. play stone more often, or always pick what the player used last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use `comp = 0`and `user = 0` above the for loop so they will not reset in each iteration. a better practice is to use classes so you can manage the game better

```
  comp = 0 # computer's score
  user = 0 # user's score
  for i in range(3):
    guess = ("stone", "paper", "scissor")# guess
    user_g = input('ENTER YOUR GUESS:')
    user_g.lower()
    comp_g = choice(guess) #computer"s guess
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you reset `comp` and `user` to `0` in each iteration of the loop. Move those lines *above* the start of the `for` loop. A few other points:

- you repeat the win/lose code six times; you could make that another function, or move the common parts of it after the different `if/else` blocks
- or you could just determine the winning/loosing guess from the order of elements in the list!
- you should check whether the user's input is valid
- in case of "draw", you should use `continue` instead of `break`
- you might add a parameter to the function for the number of rounds to play
- the function does not `return` anything, so there's no need to `print` the result

Here's my version:

```
def stone_paper_scissor(rounds):
    guess = ("stone", "paper", "scissors")
    comp = 0
    user = 0
    print("Choose either of the following:")
    print(*guess)
    for i in range(rounds):
        user_g = input('ENTER YOUR GUESS: ').lower()
        if user_g not in guess:
            print("invalid choice")
            continue
        comp_g = choice(guess)
        if comp_g == user_g:
            print( "IT'S A DRAW!" )
        elif guess[guess.index(user_g) - 1] == comp_g:
           print( "YOU WIN!" )
           user += 1
        else:
           print( "YOU LOSE!" )
           comp += 1
        print("COMPUTER " + comp_g)
        print("USER "+ user_g)
        print("USER: %d" %(user))
        print("COMPUTER: %d" %(comp))
```